# Transpose dataframe based on column list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in the following structure:

```
cNames  | cValues   |  number  
[a,b,c] | [1,2,3]   |  10      
[a,b,d] | [55,66,77]|  20
```

I would like to transpose - **create columns from the names in *cNames***.
But I can't manage to achieve this with *transpose* because I want a column for each value in the list.
The needed output:

```
a   | b   | c   | d   |  number
1   | 2   | 3   | NaN | 10
55  | 66  | NaN | 77  | 20
```

How can I achieve this result?
Thanks!

*The code to create the DF:*

```
d = {'cNames': [['a','b','c'], ['a','b','d']], 'cValues': [[1,2,3], 
[55,66,77]], 'number': [10,20]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Comment: It would be helpful to provide the code to generate your objects so people don't need to write it from scratch.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option is `concat`:

```
pd.concat([pd.Series(x['cValues'], x['cNames'], name=idx) 
               for idx, x in df.iterrows()], 
          axis=1
         ).T.join(df.iloc[:,2:])
```

Or a DataFrame construction:

```
pd.DataFrame({idx: dict(zip(x['cNames'], x['cValues']) )
              for idx, x in df.iterrows()
            }).T.join(df.iloc[:,2:])
```

Output:

```
      a     b    c     d  number
0   1.0   2.0  3.0   NaN      10
1  55.0  66.0  NaN  77.0      20
```

---

**Update** Performances sort by run time on sample data

**DataFrame**

```
%%timeit
pd.DataFrame({idx: dict(zip(x['cNames'], x['cValues']) )
              for idx, x in df.iterrows()
            }).T.join(df.iloc[:,2:])
1.29 ms ± 36.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

**concat**:

```
%%timeit
pd.concat([pd.Series(x['cValues'], x['cNames'], name=idx) 
               for idx, x in df.iterrows()], 
          axis=1
         ).T.join(df.iloc[:,2:])
2.03 ms ± 86.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

**KJDII's new series**

```
%%timeit
df['series'] = df.apply(lambda x: dict(zip(x['cNames'], x['cValues'])), axis=1)
pd.concat([df['number'], df['series'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)

2.09 ms ± 65.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

**Scott's apply(pd.Series.explode)**

```
%%timeit
df.apply(pd.Series.explode)\
  .set_index(['number', 'cNames'], append=True)['cValues']\
  .unstack()\
  .reset_index()\
  .drop('level_0', axis=1)

4.9 ms ± 135 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

**wwnde's set_index.apply(explode)**

```
%%timeit
g=df.set_index('number').apply(lambda x: x.explode()).reset_index()
g['cValues']=g['cValues'].astype(int)
pd.pivot_table(g, index=["number"],values=["cValues"],columns=["cNames"]).droplevel(0, axis=1).reset_index()

7.27 ms ± 162 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

**Celius' double explode**

```
%%timeit
df1 = df.explode('cNames').explode('cValues')
df1['cValues'] = pd.to_numeric(df1['cValues'])
df1.pivot_table(columns='cNames',index='number',values='cValues')

9.42 ms ± 189 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Yep...  constructing a new dataframe is much faster. :)

Comment: @ScottBoston actually for longer data (~2k rows), your answer comes out the fastest :-)). Following closely by the two others with `explode`.

Answer (score 7):

You can concatenate `explode()` and then pivot the table back to desired output!

```
df = df.explode('cNames').explode('cValues')
df['cValues'] = pd.to_numeric(df['cValues'])
print(df.pivot_table(columns='cNames',index='number',values='cValues'))
```

Output:

```
cNames     a     b    c     d
number                       
10       2.0   2.0  2.0   NaN
20      66.0  66.0  NaN  66.0
```

Pitifully, the output of explode is of type `object` therefore, we must transform it first to `pd.to_numeric()` before pivoting. Otherwise there will no be numeric values to aggregate.

Comment: `df.explode('cNames').explode('cValues')` looks very inneficient. Even if temporarily, It unnecessarily duplicates information.

Comment: Yes, however for two rows I really doubt it will cause any trouble

Comment: Is there more efficient solution? My real df contains much more data...

Answer (score 5):

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {'cNames': [['a','b','c'], ['a','b','d']], 'cValues': [[1,2,3], 
[55,66,77]], 'number': [10,20]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['series'] = df.apply(lambda x: dict(zip(x['cNames'], x['cValues'])), axis=1)
df = pd.concat([df['number'], df['series'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
print(df)

   number     a     b    c     d
0      10   1.0   2.0  3.0   NaN
1      20  55.0  66.0  NaN  77.0
```

if column order matters:

```py
columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'number']
df = df[columns]

      a     b    c     d  number
0   1.0   2.0  3.0   NaN      10
1  55.0  66.0  NaN  77.0      20
```

Comment: Is it more efficient than explode?

Comment: I'm not sure.  you could try both options to see which is a better fit. It's hard to compare with the current example.

Answer (score 4):

I'll toss my hat into this ring:

```
df.apply(pd.Series.explode)\
  .set_index(['number', 'cNames'], append=True)['cValues']\
  .unstack()\
  .reset_index()\
  .drop('level_0', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
cNames  number   a   b    c    d
0           10   1   2    3  NaN
1           20  55  66  NaN   77
```

Answer (score 3):

```
g=df.set_index('number').apply(lambda x: x.explode()).reset_index()
g['cValues']=g['cValues'].astype(int)
pd.pivot_table(g, index=["number"],values=["cValues"],columns=["cNames"]).droplevel(0, axis=1).reset_index()

cNames  number     a     b    c     d
0           10   1.0   2.0  3.0   NaN
1           20  55.0  66.0  NaN  77.0
```

Comment: Your code throws "AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!" at the first line (with the df I built in the question), any idea why?