# Explode multiple pandas columns and unnest one column as column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following pandas dataframe:

| name | score |
| --- | --- |
| `[A, B, C]` | `[1, 2, 0]` |
| `[A, B]` | `[1, 0]` |
| `[B, D]` | `[2, 0]` |
| `[A, B, C, D]` | `[1, 2,3,4]` |

I would  like to  get  the following pandas dataframe:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 0 | NA |
| 1 | 0 | NA | NA |
| NA | 2 | NA | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |

So far, I have done the following:

```
l_df = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    df_ = pd.DataFrame(data  = [df.iloc[i]['score']], columns = df.iloc[i]['name'])
    l_df.append(df_) 
pdf_risk_all = pd.concat(l_df)
```

However, this takes a long time and it's not good for a dataset with >1MM rows. Any suggestions to do this in a more efficient way?

Thank you,

Comment: Closely related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66070517/transpose-dataframe-based-on-column-list/66070910#66070910).

Answer (score 2):

Let's try:

```
(pd.concat([df['name'].explode(), df['score'].explode()], axis=1)
   .set_index('name',append=True)
   ['score'].unstack()
)
```

Output:

```
name    A  B    C    D
0       1  2    0  NaN
1       1  0  NaN  NaN
2     NaN  2  NaN    0
3       1  2    3    4
```

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you. Any idea how I could deduplicate entries in the 'name' column in an efficient way?
Eg: If the first row in the original dataframe was `name:[A,B, B, C],score:[1,2,2,0] `

Comment: `df = df[~df.index.duplicated(keep='first')]` helped.

Answer (score 0):

In pyspark dataframe, you can zip columns `score` and `name` using `arrays_zip` function, then explode and pivot :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F


df1 = df.withColumn("idx", F.monotonically_increasing_id()) \
    .withColumn("name_score", F.explode(F.arrays_zip("name", "score"))) \
    .select("idx", "name_score.*") \
    .groupBy("idx").pivot("name").agg(first("score")).drop("idx")

df1.show(truncate=False)

#+----+---+----+----+
#|A   |B  |C   |D   |
#+----+---+----+----+
#|1   |2  |0   |null|
#|1   |2  |3   |4   |
#|null|2  |null|0   |
#|1   |0  |null|null|
#+----+---+----+----+
```