# explode a pandas dataframe using two comma separated columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data which is packed a lot of values into row, but i would like to have to converted to row wise data to make it usable.
below is how my input looks like. i would like to explode this dataset. i am able to do if its for single column, but i am unable to achieve same result for combination of two column. is the below achievable using pandas?

```
import pandas as pd
data = [{'col1':'val1','col2':'val2','col3':'aaa,bbb,ccc','col4':'ddd,eee,fff'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Input

```
col1  col2         col3         col4
val1  val2  aaa,bbb,ccc  ddd,eee,fff
```

Desired Output

```
col1  col2         col3         col4
val1  val2         aaa          ddd
val1  val2         aaa          eee
val1  val2         aaa          fff
val1  val2         bbb          ddd
val1  val2         bbb          eee
val1  val2         bbb          fff
val1  val2         ccc          ddd
val1  val2         ccc          eee
val1  val2         ccc          fff
```

Comment: related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66070517/transpose-dataframe-based-on-column-list/66070910#66070910).

Answer (score 1):

You can just explode twice:

```
(df.assign(col3=df.col3.str.split(','),
           col4=df.col4.str.split(','))
   .explode('col3')
   .explode('col4')
).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
    col1    col2    col3    col4
0   val1    val2    aaa     ddd
1   val1    val2    aaa     eee
2   val1    val2    aaa     fff
3   val1    val2    bbb     ddd
4   val1    val2    bbb     eee
5   val1    val2    bbb     fff
6   val1    val2    ccc     ddd
7   val1    val2    ccc     eee
8   val1    val2    ccc     fff
```